# bundle product keep out of stock

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

In these few days, I have tested **magento2 bundle product** function in a **multi-site** magento2.
However, there is a problem.

First, I have two sites which are TW and US.
I followed the document in Magento website for setting up a test bundle product.

> http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-bundle.html

I am able to find that product in TW but not in the US.
And then I directly accessed that product page, I found It is out of stock.
But I have set as in stock.
[image]

Please give me some advice.

Thank you

Comment: Is this with manage stock set to no? I have also just noticed this issue with my manage stock set to no

Comment: It would become out of stock if there is an included 'Disabled' product.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:

Edit the bundle product -> Advanced inventory -> manage stock "no"

Comment: it's not working in magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I just set manage stock "no" in configuration, but no have a sucess. 
When you have store view the stock not working